# Speed up sed on a gz file

Tags: performance, file, sed, gzip

I'm using a script to `sed` a file and remove text this way:

```
gzip -cd /data/file.gz | sed 's/WITH (appendonly=true, compresstype=quicklz)//' | gzip > file_seeded.gz
```

It takes a lot of time to perform the operation on big files (50GB for example). Is the way I'm doing this the optimal way or there are alternatives to speed up the process?

Comment: 50GB is a lot and I don't think you can speed up `sed` here, other than using `LC_ALL=C sed '...'` if your input is ASCII... I'd suggest https://github.com/chmln/sd for better speed than sed, or even https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/545645#545645 for examples)

Comment: Agree with all of above, and will add that unless you can change the producer process to create smaller  (and more) files, those alternate utilities are your best bet. If you had multiple parts to your file (created automatically), then you could use `xargs` or `gnu-parallel` to have multiple `sed`s running on the same "set" of data. But, I think the `| gzip > outFile` is probably the most expensive process there (unless you have a crazy `sed` file), so don't expect too much improvement. Maybe some quick tests first are in order. Good luck!

Comment: And I don't think that trying to split the big file, before running mutltiple seds will save you any time, but ... who knows, depending on how much you value reducing this run time, it might shave off a few seconds, so again, quick tests will help you know you've covered every possibility. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid recompressing the edited data, which dominates the execution time. All I can suggest would be to use `gzip -1` or `gzip -3` to speed up the compression at the cost of slightly larger output. You can also use [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) to make use of all of your cores.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact, that you can append multiple gzip files:

```
mysed() {
  sed 's/WITH (appendonly=true, compresstype=quicklz)//' | gzip
}
export -f mysed
gzip -cd /data/file.gz | parallel --pipe -k --block 50M mysed > file_seeded.gz
```

Adjust `50M` until you find the value that works best. It depends on how fast I/O to  /tmp is and how much RAM and CPU cache you have. The best value will most likely be between 1M and 1000M.

If time is more important than disk space use `gzip -1`.